# PyMEL giving errors in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, maya

I configured Eclipse for Maya scripting. When I tried to run the following script I got the error. But maya.cmds module works not PyMEL.

```
import pymel.core as pm
pm.polySphere()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shivani\workspace\pythonFirst\firstModule.py", line 1, in <module>
import pymel.core as pm
  File "C:\pymel-1.0.3\pymel\core\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
import pymel.versions as _versions
  File "C:\pymel-1.0.3\pymel\versions.py", line 57, in <module>
_current = _MGlobal.apiVersion()
TypeError: unbound method apiVersion() must be called with MGlobal instance as first   argument (got nothing instead)
```

Comment: the output of `sys.path`?

Comment: Did you install pymel yourself ?, maya is shipping with pymel now. And if you installing yourself then follow this http://pymel.googlecode.com/svn/docs/install.html

Comment: @hus787 sorry I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: what is the result of `import sys;print sys.path`?

Comment: You have to install pymel manually, it just doesn't 'work' out of the box.http://3dtoolsdevelopment.blogspot.com.au/2010/11/setting-up-eclipse-as-pymel-editor.html

Comment: @ShannonHochkins I followed every step mentioned there but the same issue.

Comment: @hus787 its too long so not enough space here. But it includes pymel too.

Comment: try removing the pymel entry and see if the above code works. If `os.getenv("PYTHONPATH")` includes pymel then remove it from the `PYTHONPATH` user/system environment variable.

Comment: @hus787 I did that but I get the same error.

Comment: @zingy Start Maya (not Mayabatch) `import pymel` and then `print pymel` in the script editor. What do you get? The idea is to append that some root of that path you get to `os.path`.

Comment: @ hus787 When I do that I get <module 'pymel' from 'C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2013\Python\lib\site-packages\pymel\__init__.py'>

Comment: @zingy Prepend `C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2013\Python\lib\site-packages` to `sys.path` (`sys.path.insert(0, the_path)`). You added a space between `@` and `h` in the previous comment therefore I wasn't notified/[pinged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125208/221866)

Comment: @hus787 That was silly of me. I have not used Eclipse these days. I still get errors so I have given up for now. When I start using Eclipse again then will see what happens. Thanks anyway.